# Flask Blueprint : how to run each apps in different port?

Tags: flask, blueprint

I got a flask application with different apps inside, using BluePrint.
To simplify, I got an API that manages token web authentification (and a lot of other data functions) and a website that should call the API to get the valid token, using a basic auth to start with

The issue is that when the website requests the API, it never gets any feedback from the API.

Requesting the API via **POSTMAN** works like a charm, but this call below, done from a website route is waiting, waiting, waiting and never ends.

So my assumption is that using the same port for both website and api is the issue

I could of course divides the flask into 2 flask apps with 2 servers, but there are many objects and tools both API and website are sharing, so I dont want to double the job

Thanks.

**call from the website**

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

mod = Blueprint('site', __name__, template_folder='templates/login')

def load_user(username, password):
     data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login', 
                 auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
     return data

@mod.route('/')
def index():
     username = 'jeje'
     password = 'jeje'
     data = load_user(username, password)
     return '<h1>load user<h1>'
```

**the api function**

```
@mod.route('/login')
def login():
    resu = True
    auth = request.authorization
    if not auth or not auth.username or not auth.password:
        resu = False
    user = USER.query.filter_by(username = auth.username).first()
    if not user:
        resu = False

    if validehash(user.password, auth.password):
        period_in_mn = 120
        payload = {
            'public_id':user.public_id,
            'exp' : datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes = period_in_mn)
        }
        token = createtoken(payload, current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    if resu:
        return jsonify({'token' : token })
    else:
        return jsonify({'token' : 'unknown'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your using flask 0.12 instead of 1.0. So whats happening here is that you're requesting a route from within another route.

Your browser requests `/`, and in your index function, you request `/login`. But the flask process is still working on the `/` request from the browser, and can't take any other requests, because flask 0.12 is working on a single core only.

Requesting like this is bad design. You could make a helper function, which returns the same data in different requests (either api or main site), or you could make the browser send another request using AJAX.

Flask 1.0 has multicore support, so I think this might work over there, but I really think you should change your design. This has absolutely nothing to do with blueprints by the way.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    result = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login')
    return 'this is the index<br>' + result.text

@app.route('/api/login')
def login():
    return 'you are logged in'
```

Using flask 0.12, times out when visiting `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.

Using flask 1.0, returns `this is the index
you are logged in` when visiting  `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.

Comment: dear, ok got it, will try to do helper functions instead